# Calculate the area defined by a circle and a line by using double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to calculate the area by using double integrals.

This is the integral:

\begin{equation*}
 \iint \limits_{D}xy^2 \,dx\,dy
\end{equation*}

This is the domain D:
\begin{cases}
\ x+y \geq 1 \\[2ex]
x^2+y^2 \leq 1
\end{cases}
By writing the equations which determine the domain I get this:
[image: Circle with the line.]

The area in blue must be calculated.

Now i know that x moves along only 0 and 1, I can not figure out the limits for y. I will be thankful if you can help me.
The answer provided is: 1/20.

Comment: The lower limit is given by the line $y=1-x$ and the upper limit by the line $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, with $0<x<1$

Comment: @CooperCape that gives the right answer, thank you very much, but will you please explain me why is it like that, I am a bit puzzled.

Comment: By the inequalities given in the question - we have $y\geq 1-x$ and $y^2\leq 1-x^2$

Comment: I suppose this works for most of the problems of this kind. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The chord is $\;y=1-x\;$ , the circle is $\;x^2+y^2=1\;$ , and 
you want the part on the first quadrant between the chord and the circle.

$$\int_0^1\int_{1-x}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}xy^2\,dy\,dx=\frac13\int_0^1x\left((1-x^2)^{3/2}-(1-x)^3\right)dx=$$

$$=-\left.\frac16\frac25(1-x^2)^{5/2}\right|_0^1-\frac13\int_0^1x(1-3x+3x^2-x^3)\,dx=$$

$$=-\frac1{15}(0-1)-\frac13\left(\frac12-1+\frac34-\frac15\right)=\frac1{15}-\frac16+\frac13-\frac14+\frac1{15}=$$

$$=\frac{8-10+20-15}{60}=\frac1{20}$$

Comment: May I ask you how you made the calculations so fast?

Comment: @tgarmp The last ones? Simple arithmetic For the integrals it is almost immediate: $$\int x(1-x^2)^{3/2}\,dx=-\frac12\int d(1-x^2)\,(1-x^2)^{3/2}$$ and etc.

Answer (score 1):

We require $$D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R : x^2 + y^2 \le 1 \le x+y\}.$$  Noting that this implies $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$, we can solve the associated inequalities for $x$ as a function of $y$ on the interval $y \in [0,1]$:  $$\sqrt{1-y^2} \le x \le 1 - y.$$  Consequently, $$\iint_D xy^2 \, dx \, dy = \int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{1-y} x y^2 \, dx \, dy.$$

Answer (score 0):

I would convert to polar.  Then the region becomes:

$r = [\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sec (\theta - \frac {\pi}{4}),1]$

or $r = [\frac {1}{\cos\theta + \sin\theta},1]$

Comment: That region you depict there, which I cannot understand, has $\;\theta\;$ all around the circle. Yet the region exists only on the first quadrant...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I gave you the complimentary region.  I will edit.